# Store won't open after upgrade

Tags: windows-store, windows-8.1

After upgrading Windows 8 Enterprise to Windows 8.1 Enterprise (RTM), the store app won't launch anymore, hanging on the splash screen forever. Is there a trick to reset the store app or something? Restarting or killing the app didn't work. There are no error messages in the event logs (`TWinUI/Operational` etc.).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this on another forum. Open a command prompt and run the following:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Add-AppxPackage
           -DisableDevelopmentMode 
           -Register $Env:SystemRoot\WinStore\AppxManifest.xml
```

(All on one line.)

Answer (score 3):

Method 1: I would suggest you to download and run the New UI App troubleshooter and check if Windows Store works.

http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/2/4/F24D0C03-4181-4E5B-A23B-5C3A6B5974E3/apps.diagcab

Method 2: Check if the date, time and time zone are set according to your time and time zone.

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1_pr-windows_store/why-is-windows-store-not-working-after-windows-81/941645b6-714d-4aa8-8a71-d62809895cbd)

Comment: Thanks. The troubleshooter detected some corrupted files and repaired them, but that didn't fix the issue. Date & time settings are correct.

Comment: Didn't work for me either, but I too had corrupted files.

Answer (score 0):

For People that are experiencing a similar problem, where you get an error message saying something like:

```
"We weren't able to connect to the Store. This might have happened 
    because of a server problem or the network....blah blah blah"
```

And the above methods will not work, here is the solution:

1.) Go to **Settings**

2.) Then **Change PC Settings**

3.) Then **Your Account**

4.) Then you should see a little link to the right that says `Verify Your Identity`

5.) Click that link, and type in your password that you use to login to your pc.

6.) Go to Task Manager to close the Store

7.) Profit!

Hope this helps!

I experienced this when using the 8.1 beta, when the beta expired and I tried to download the newest version of Windows I ran into this problem and searched, and searched, and searched.....and found many solutions like the ones above, until I finally came across a blog that described the above method.

Answer (score 0):

Check your network connection, if you have google DNS server try remove it or put your gateway IP. I had this before problem but after I remove google DNS server (8.8.8.8) and I changed it to my router IP it fix the problem and windows store started.