# How do I fix the Microsoft Store "Page could not be loaded. Please try again later." error?

Tags: windows-10

I am getting an annoying error which is preventing me from downloading any app on windows 10 Enterprise Build 14393.1884.

The exact error is:

"Try that again.Page could not be loaded. Please try again later." 
Code: 0x80131500

**What I've tried:**

- Running the wsreset.exe to reset the windows store.
- Opening the powershell as admin and running `Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`
- Ran the application debugger to trouble shoot it, which didn't do anything noteworthy.
- Modified the DNS records to see if that helped. It did not.
- Went to Settings > Apps & Features > Store and did a "reset"
- Updated to the latest version of Windows 10.
- Changed my region settings and restarted the machine.
- Ran the windows update troubleshooter
- Restarting, after each step, and logging out/back in etc.

None of these things seem to have any effect on the store not responding.

Comment: I have only ever seen this when the user had a DNS issue.  Chnage your DNS provider

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store won't open after upgrade](https://superuser.com/questions/650972/store-wont-open-after-upgrade)

Comment: What build of Windows 10 Enterprise are you using?  What release channel have you configured your system to use.

Comment: @Ramhound Updated the build info. I have automatic updates on and I recently manually checked for updates which there were none available.

Comment: [14393.1884](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4048953) was released back in November.  You haven’t installed an update in 3 months.  Additionally, 1607 suggests you might be using the LTSB version of Windows Enterprise.  *I really appreciate all of my feedback being addressed*.  Windows Store is intentionally not suppose to work on LTSB.  What type of role are you asking this question?  The problem will require an Administrator user to solve, but simply updating, might help

Comment: @Ramhound Can you clarify what you mean by "1607" as I'm not familiar with that. I don't think I have LTSB though, it should show under system settings if so. I'm installing the latest updates and will report back later.

Comment: @leigero @ramhound means that you are on Version 1607, Build 14393.1884. More info: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4048953/windows-10-update-kb4048953 Check "applies to". Alternatively, checking for cb/ltsd, open powershell and run `gwmi win32_operatingsystem | select OperatingSystemSKU`
A value of 4 means CB while 125 means LTSB

Comment: Winver should display that information.  You are an Administrator? This isn’t something a non-Administrator can solve.  Clicking on the link I provided as 1607 on it, so have you, even checked that page out?

Comment: @Ramhound So I ran the powershell script and got a 4 so it's definitely cb. Also I just installed the latest updates and reset the store, still not working. Yes I am an administrator on the machine.

Comment: I had this same issue and was about to do a full repair or reformat of Windows when I realized that I'd been ignoring that Windows Explorer didn't process file updates.  I googled that and followed instructions on this link to run Windows SFC and DISM tools for file system repair, and *that* is what fixed it.  I checked the logs and there was a corrupted driver file.  Note this is a pretty clean dev system with no hacked, pirated, etc installs.  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/file-explorer-doesnt-refresh-automatically/ade12179-e1e0-4c16-8530-37fc49a3815a

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the source of this issues was with the company IT department. While I have local admin rights the store was blocked by the company for whatever reason. It was later re-opened and users were allowed to access it again.

I know this may not be the helpful answer viewers are looking for, but in my case this was resolved only by putting in an internal support ticket to the IT department.